# How do I calculate the average length of a string in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, average, string-length

How do I calculate the average length of a string in my array?  I thought I could do

```
2.4.0 :004 >   arr = ["a", "ab", "abc"]
 => ["a", "ab", "abc"]
...
2.4.0 :006 > arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el.length }.to_f / arr.size
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String
    from (irb):6:in `+'
    from (irb):6:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):6:in `each'
    from (irb):6:in `inject'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `my_command!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

but apparently not.

Comment: I think the answers given here are better than the ones in the "duplicate" link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write like:

```
arr.join.size / arr.size.to_f
```

Also, you can use `sum` since Ruby 2.4:

```
arr.sum(&:size) / arr.size.to_f
#=> 2.0
```

Comment: `sum` works only from ruby 2.4.0

Comment: @Ursus, thanks for the note, I added it.

Comment: I think you can improve again: `arr.map(&:size).sum` into `arr.sum(&:size)`

Comment: True, the first one in the ruby 2.4.0 part doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, to me too.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was Rails `sum` :)

Answer (score 3):

Before Ruby 2.4.0

```
arr.inject(0) { |acc, s| acc + s.length } / arr.size.to_f
```

After Ruby 2.4.0

```
arr.sum(&:length) / arr.size.to_f
```

Comment: `sum` makes this much more elegant.  I'd be curious (but don't have time right now) to see how they compare w/ benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

`inject` takes a starting value for `sum`. It's defaulting to a `String`. This works:

```
arr.inject(0) { |sum, el| sum + el.length }.to_f / arr.size
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'

arr = ["a", "ab", "abc"]

puts "Ruby #{RUBY_VERSION}"

compare do
  ilya1 { arr.join.size / arr.size.to_f }
  ilya2 { arr.sum(&:size) / arr.size.to_f }
  derrell_durrett { arr.inject(0) { |sum, el| sum + el.length }.to_f / arr.size }
  ursus1 { arr.inject(0) { |acc, s| acc + s.length } / arr.size.to_f }
  ursus2 { arr.sum(&:length) / arr.size.to_f }
end

# >> Ruby 2.4.1
# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> ursus2 is similar to ilya2
# >> ilya2 is faster than ilya1 by 2x ± 0.1
# >> ilya1 is similar to ursus1
# >> ursus1 is similar to derrell_durrett
```

Basically `ursus2` and `ilya2` are identical, since [`size` is an alias of `length`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-size).

Comment: I used `benchmark-ips` instead of `fruity`, and found essentially the same at the top end (`ursus2` and `ilya2` were tied for first), but `ilya1` was a wee bit slower than the two `inject`-based solutions.

Comment: When Fruity says something is similar, it's generally within 10%. 10% can be the result of system activity slowing the tests. It's more important when we're seeing multiples, like `ilya2 is faster than ilya1 by 2x ± 0.1`.

Comment: `benchmark-ips` is similar, in that it calculates a confidence interval on each result and considers overlapping confidence intervals interchangeable.  It also does a warmup before running each for 5 seconds.  It reported that `ursus2` and `ilya2` were effectively tied, `derrell_durrett` and `ursus1` were about 1.6 times slower than the top two, and that `ilya1` was about 1.67 times slower than the top two.